# How to call 2 child functions in one main function

Tags: javascript

I have several functions in JavaScript whose results I want to use in an `if` statement in another function.

My problem is that only the first listed child function seems to be returning a result. When I swap the order of the functions around then I still only get a returning result from the child function listed first.

I'm a beginner and not all that familiar with functions just yet. See my example below. Please be specific with any answers.

```
function main(a) {
  return functone(x);  // name of function is actually "functone" for this example
  return functtwo(y);  // name of function is actually "functtwo" for this example

  if(functone(x)!="true") {
    return false;
  } else {
    if(functtwo(y)!="true) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't return two values from one function. So your code should be

```
function main(a){
if(functone(x)!="true")
  {return false;} else 
     {if(functtwo(y)!="true")
         {return false;} else {return true;}
     }
}
```

Comment: @user2337745 in that case, please consider accepting my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It *appears* that you want to only want to return `true` only if both of the called functions do.

A typical pattern for this would be:

```
function main(a) {
    return functone(x) && functwo(y);
}
```

Note that in this case `functwo` will *only* be called if the result of `funcone` is `false` (or more strictly "falsey", i.e. also including `null` or `0`) because the `&&` operator is what's called a *short circuit operator*.  If the result of the operation can be determined directly from the left hand operand, the right hand operand is not evaluated.

If you want `functwo` to be called regardless of the outcome of `funcone` then replace the `&&` operator with the bitwise `&` operator.

Note that your `funcXXX` functions ought (like this function) to return the propert boolean value `true` or `false`, and not the string `"true"`.